# Find squares amongst a set of trees

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list, find, time-complexity

Suppose we are a hunter in a forest with N trees. In order to hunt the best deer we intend to build fences from tree to tree such that we end up with an exact square. Suppose further that we are given a list of (x,y) coordinates for each of the N trees in the forest. We want to find the largest possible square and the total number of possible squares of any size? Aim for O(N^2).

For example, the list (4, 10), (3, 13), (2, 10), (1, 13), (3, 11), (5, 11), (4, 14), (1, 11), (9, 15), (9, 11), (5, 15) contains three possible squares and the largest square amongst those three is comprised of (5, 11), (9, 15), (9, 11), (5, 15).

---

My basic attempt is to write a for-loop that goes through the entire list of points (from 1 to N), then include a second for-loop that goes through all the points again, from i to N, where i is the current increment of the first for-loop. These two points now uniquely determine the remaining two points. Thus we need one more for-loop (starting from j, where j is the current increment of the second for-loop) that checks whether these two remaining points exist or not. If they exist, then we have found a square. After having found all squares it's trivial to find the largest one.

However, this idea requires three for-loops, i.e. O(N^3). So I am wondering how one could optimise this code to achieve O(N^2).

Comment: does those squares need to be aligned to the co-ordinate system? Eg. (1,0), (0,1), (1,2), (2,1) is a valid answer?

Comment: @ElKamina Yes, your example is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

> These two points now uniquely determine the remaining two points.

Your idea is spot-on: iterate over each side, and try building two squares around it (one square will be the mirror image of the other).

> However, this idea requires three for-loops, i.e. O(N^3). So I am wondering how one could optimise this code to achieve O(N^2).

You can replace the third loop with a hash table lookup, which is O(1). Building the hash table takes
 O(N), so the overall timing of your algorithm will be O(N^2).